# How to get full double value

Tags: c#, double

I want get full double value in c#, for EX:

```
double a = 984554546543213213215465879875645432132112548787;
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

//get: 984554546543213213215465879875645432132112548787

but get 9.84554546543213E+47

I use [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) but its not working, its get:

//984554546543213265388222902015563129359765078016

Comment: On my C# compiler (of Visual Studio 2013) you need to append `.0` or `d` or similar to the numerical literal to make this compile. The number you get is not exact. The represented value corresponds to `6067785865824547 * 2**107`, so it is a relatively small "general" integer times a huge power of two (I used `**` to denote exponentiation). That is how binary floating point types work. There is no way you can fit general 48-digit whole numbers into a data type (`double`) with just 64 bits.

Comment: System.Numerics.BigInteger is class you need for such big numbers. Of course, if your Net framework has this class (starting from 4.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubles simply don't have enough accuracy for this application. It's not a problem with the displaying of the value; it's a problem with how a `double` is actually stored and how it's inherently approximate.

Based on the example given, you might want to take a look a the [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

`decimal` might also be worth looking at.

Comment: One `decimal` value by itself does not have the required precision either. Its precision is near 28 decimal figures, compared to the approx. 16 decimal figures of `double`. The number from the question has 48 figures.